# Roommate got a dog, but lease said no pets, now what?

Tags: united-states, landlord, nevada

My roommate's boyfriend's dog is living in our shared apartment. She has essentially adopted it. Our lease that I signed said `no pets`.

[image]

My landlord found out about the dog and let her keep it. Neither one of them consulted me and I definitely do not want it living here. What recourse do I have besides moving out when the lease is up? Can I break the lease?

Comment: Typically, contract modifications require the agreement of all parties to the original contract.  Often contracts will have additional clauses that explicitly discuss how modifications are to be handled and whether the the contract represents the entire agreement.

Answer (score 1):

You can sue your co-tenant for breaching the lease, either for damages or a court order that she remove the dog. Just because the landlord waived his right to do so doesn't mean that you have. The lease is a contract between the three of you.

You cannot terminate (which I think is what you mean by "break") the lease as the landlord has not given you any cause to do so.

Of course, you might as well move out because suing your co-tenant is a pretty toxic move.

Comment: Yes, I meant `terminate`. Yeah, I'm going to move out.

Comment: Not that I'm going to, but any links to cases where tenants sued their co-tenants for breaching the lease and got damages would be useful.